# WPF panel header title

Tags: c#, wpf

I am not sure they correct terminology for a header/title bar of a component in WPF. What I need is a panel/non-floating window, in which I can set the title? I want a few components in a panel that needs a title like Properties and Toolbox in Visual Studio.

As mentioned earlier, this doesn't need to be a floating/docking panel. I don't want GroupBox. I will be adding close button later just to hide the component from the user.

Comment: Do you need to be able to drag it around like a window? If I were doing this and it didn't have to be mobile I'd be tempted just to use a lightly styled 2 row Grid with a TextBlock in the top row. You can show/hide it just by binding to its Visibility property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think, that in `WPF` visual solutions are limited only by our imagination.
If there isn't the control you want - you can build it.

My simple solution is here:

```
<Border Visibility="Visible" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Blue" CornerRadius="8" Margin="30,30,30,30">
    <StackPanel Margin="3">
        <Label  Height="25" Content="H e a d e r" Background="LightSkyBlue" />
            <Separator Height="5"/>
            <Grid>
                <!-- content -->
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
```

Changing `Visibility="Collapsed"` you can hide this "panel".

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need it to undock and float then you can use a [HeaderedContentControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headeredcontentcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

When you want to add the close button you can template the header presenter to include a button.